# Why does website cause most elements to be recalculated upon small change after being hosted?

Tags: javascript, performance, hosting, github-pages

I decided to make a Pac-Man game and after I did it and everything was working somewhat fine on local document I pushed my website on Github pages and decrease in fps was enormous. It turned out page was making recalculation for hundreds elements which caused 20ms+ delay.

Here's a small part of the code that still has performance difference between local and github-pages hosted website.

```js
const gameBoard = document.getElementById("game-board");
const root = document.documentElement.style;

let elements;
let characterNode;
let position = 658;

makeLevel();

function makeLevel() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 868; i++) {
        const element = document.createElement("DIV");
        element.style.backgroundPosition = `0 0`;

        let character = document.createElement("DIV");
        character.className = "yellow";
        element.append(character);
        gameBoard.append(element);
    }
    elements = Array.from(gameBoard.children);
    characterNode = elements[658].children[0];
    changePosition();
}
function changePosition() {
    root.setProperty(`--yellow-sprite-y`, `-32px`);
    characterNode.style.transform = `translateX(-20px)`;

    setTimeout(() => {
        characterNode.style.transform = "";
        characterNode.classList.remove(`yellow-visible`);
        position = position - 1;
        characterNode = elements[position].children[0];
        characterNode.classList.add(`yellow-visible`);
        changePosition()
    }, 200)
}
```

```css
:root {
  --yellow-sprite-y: -32px;
}
#game-board {
  width: 560px;
  height: 620px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(28, 20px);
  background-color: #000000;
}
#game-board > * {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.yellow {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -5.5px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 28px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.yellow-visible {
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/SphNpH6.png");
  background-position: -32px var(--yellow-sprite-y);
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}
```

```html
    <div id="game-board">
    </div>
```

The exact problem in this code is line 29 which on local document performs like this:
[image]

while after hosting it on Github performs this way:

[image]

Why is it working this way and what can I do to lessen the performance decrease on hosted page?

Amazingly everything works well and bug doesn't exist on CodePen, yet on Github it still persists.

Comment: No, the only thing affecting JS runtime performance are the engine and the device it runs on. Also making things "asynchronous" does not necessarily speed up things.

Comment: *"Does hosted websites run slower than those ran locally?"* No. *"Is this because of Github Pages?"* Probably not. *"Is there a quick fix for website performing a lot slower than localhost?"* It's impossible to say without seeing the code. But *don't* post it all (or a link to it) in your question. Instead, go through the process of reducing it to the minimum possible described here: [mcve].

Comment: *"I decided to make this game in vanilla js, that means without canvas"* No, it doesn't. Presumably you're doing *something* to display where things are -- apparently not a canvas, but perhaps the DOM, etc. The DOM is not part of JavaScript any more than canvas is (indeed, canvas is part of the DOM).

Comment: For your information, I deleted some content that was unnecessary or which comments have already answered to bring attention to the main problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting some feedback that my site works well for other users I shared it on CodePen and it also worked fine, day later somebody said there could be an extension that could do something like that and indeed [Adblocker Ultimate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblocker-ultimate/ohahllgiabjaoigichmmfljhkcfikeof?hl=en) caused the slow performance.